# Ter imagens nas tabelas onde serão usadas ou tabela com repositório de imagens?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

É uma boa prática criar uma tabela para registrar todas as imagens de um banco de dados, ou posso criar as colunas que salva as informações da imagem para cada necessidade em específico?

Por exemplo, vamos supor que eu queira criar uma tabela para categorias de um site e cada categoria da tabela possuísse uma imagem.

```
tlb_category
- id
- title
- img_name
- img_ext
- date_created
- date_updated
- status
```

ou é mais correto assim?

```
tlb_category
- id
- title
- img_id
- date_created
- date_updated
- status

tbl_image
- id
- img_name
- img_ext
- date_created
- date_updated
- status
```

Qual é melhor para uma boa prática? Tem alguma outra sugestão? A segunda forma me parece mais correto, mas é normal ter várias imagens das categorias, dos produtos, avatares dos usuários, etc... Tudo misturado em uma tabela?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As duas formas podem estar corretas dependendo do que deseja.

A imagem faz parte das informações da categoria? Há uma relação de 1 para 1 entre a categoria e imagem? Ou seja, não há várias imagens para a categoria, nem uma imagem poderá ser usada em mais de uma categoria? As leituras (quase) sempre precisarão da informação da imagem?

Então parece que a primeira não tem nada de errado, simplifica bastante o processo. Separar esta informação em outra tabela não parece trazer nenhuma vantagem e não está sequer fazendo [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101).

A segunda é interessante se você está trabalhando com um repositório de imagens, ou se não atende aos requisitos anteriores, então pode ser necessário normalizar a informação. De fato como você tem várias informações específicas sobre a imagem, pode poluir um pouco a tabela de categoria, mas este não deve ser o critério para adotá-lo. Se a imagem funciona de forma independente é um bom motivo para tê-la separada.

Aí você tem que se perguntar qual a vantagem de usar a segunda? O que você perde se usar a primeira? Organizar por organizar sem ter um ganho não é um boa coisa. Organizar deve eliminar redundância, deve tornar a informação canônica. Se isto pode ser obtido com a primeira forma vá com ela, será mais performático e mais simples lidar com isto. Se entender que há ou pode haver um prejuízo no futuro, vá com a segunda.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Interessante resposta. Sim, é uma relação de 1 para 1, uma categoria só pode ter uma imagem. Só que vou complementar: Neste banco de dados, não irá existir somente essa tabela de categorias com imagens. Existirá outras tabelas (produtos, avatares dos usuários) que irão precisar de imagens, neste caso, seria mais vantajoso criar uma tabela para armazenar todas as imagens? Ou usar uma tabela para cada necessidade ainda pode ser mais vantajoso?

Comment: Ainda depende. Se as imagens são sempre parte integrante de onde ela vai ser usada, e não independente, não tem porque fazer isto. Se a imagem é algo independente e por acaso será anexada a outro item do banco de dados, então é interessante. Depende do grau de associatividade. Tem que conceituar bem o que precisa para saber como implementar. Ninguém vai conseguir conceituar o melhor para você a não ser que faça todo o trabalho de levantamento. Se tudo será um relacionamento de 1:1 eu, **provavelmente**, colocaria nas respectivas tabelas. Até que eu descubra um motivo para evitar isto.

Comment: Legal. Gostei do seu conselho, eu havia pensado nisso, de se ia compensar criar uma tabela geral de imagens ou não. Acabei por decidir que não farei isso, porque por exemplo essas imagens pertencentes a categoria não irá ser aproveitado em nenhum outro lugar se não as categorias. Marquei a sua como resposta, muito obrigado!

Comment: Na verdade, não marcou.

Comment: Oxe, agora marcou, hahaha.

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta - porém, você percebeu que do segundo para o primeiro exemplo, diversas informações estão sendo desprezadas? Isso decide para mim, de cara, qual modelo deve ser utilizado. Usando o primeiro modelo, ele nunca poderá saber quando uma imagem foi atualizada, porque ele **não tem** esta informação - simples assim.

Comment: Eu leio a pergunta do @ThiagoYoithi assim: Qual o melhor modelo, o que eu jogo metade das minhas informações fora, ou o que não?

Comment: @DanielGomes não consigo ver o que você viu.

Comment: Você não lê o `date_created` da `tbl_image` como a data em que a imagem foi criada? E o `date_created` da `tlb_category` como a data em que foi inserido um novo registro na categoria? Eu vejo 7 itens contra 11!

Comment: @DanielGomes mas deve ser a mesma informação, o que inclusive na segunda ficaria redundante. Mas se não for, se puder ter uma data diferente, então basta criar uma coluna para guardar esta data na primeira.

Comment: E você acha que o @ThiagoYoithi sabe disso? E só cometeu um *deslize* ao duplicar todos os dados? ;)

Comment: @DanielGomes aí eu não sei, mas não é difícil perceber a hora que estiver montando isto.

Comment: Ahaha, estou ciente disso. Vou pensar como irei fazer, mas você tem razão @DanielGomes, na primeira forma não é possível guardar a data em que a imagem foi criada. Porém essa não é uma informação tão útil no contexto da minha aplicação, visto que será obrigatória a imagem na criação da categoria. Penso que poderei usar a tabela bem parecido com a primeira forma, guardando somente a data de cadastro e atualização da categoria.

Comment: @ThiagoYoithi até acho que não precisa mesmo, mas porque não dá para guardar a data? Só se for porque não tem campo. Aí basta criá-lo, se for útil.

Answer (score 4):

A segunda forma, <s>definitivamente</s><sup>(1)</sup>.

Uma imagem é uma imagem, independentemente do que ela representa.
O que não é "normal" é misturar informações(campos) relativos à categoria com informações(campos) relativos à imagem.

Isto tem haver com o conceito de [normalização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization):

> Normalização é o processo de organizar as colunas e tabelas de um banco de dados relacional para minimizar a redundância de dados.
>   Normalização envolve a decomposição de uma tabela em tabelas menos redundantes e menores, sem perda de informações.
>   (...)
>   <sub>[Tradução da Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)</sub>

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> Na sua resposta, o @Maniero refere uma questão relevante que eu inicialmente não tive em conta.

De facto, no caso de relações 1:1, talvez não seja proveitoso fazer a separação dos dados da imagem em outra tabela.

No entanto, no cenário provável em que os dados da categoria sejam muito mais vezes acedidos do que os dados da imagem, poderá ser mais eficiente fazê-la.

A BD gere uma cache com os dados mais frequentemente lidos. Normalmente essa cache é feita ao nível da linha e não ao nível das colunas. Estaríamos, assim, a colocar em cache dados que são pouco vezes necessários.

Isto ainda se tornaria mais ineficiente se a imagem fosse guardada em um campo *BLOB*</sub>

Comment: Hmmmm. Entendi, me desculpe não ter comentado nada antes. Teve bastante informações úteis no seu comentário, irei levar isso em consideração. Na minha aplicação, as imagens não são guardados em campos BLOB, pois estou armazenando as imagens na Amazon S3 e guardando somente o nome do arquivo no BD. Acredito que as duas formas tem suas vantagens e desvantagens, já fiz a minha decisão.